# How can I list all available windows locales in python console?

Tags: python, locale

On linux we can use `locale -a` to see the list of locales available.

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Is it possible to do the same from python console on **windows**?

This can be handy when you try to do `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '???')` and simply don't know the name of the locale value.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.locale_alias
```

Comment: I just found out that ?(at least on a linux system),  not all actually  existing (and instaled) locales  are listed in this dictionary. I did `[item for item in locale.locale_alias.items() if "pt_br" in item[0].lower()]` and got as a result: `[('pt_br.iso88591', 'pt_BR.ISO8859-1'), ('pt_br.88591', 'pt_BR.ISO8859-1'), ('pt_br', 'pt_BR.ISO8859-1'), ('pt_br@euro', 'pt_BR.ISO8859-15'), ('pt_br.iso885915', 'pt_BR.ISO8859-15')]` - the problerm is I have a ut-f8 pt_BR locale not listed above-  the following works: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "pt_BR.utf-8")`

Comment: `locale_alias` does not work on Windows (checked on Python 2.7.8 Windows 7)

Comment: To be clear: the values from `locale_alias` do not work on Windows.

Comment: I found this to include far more locales than are actually available, as determined by trying to `setlocale(LC_ALL, ...)` some of them. It certainly includes far more than are in my `locale -a` output.

It also _didn't_ include 3 of the 4 entries that were in `locale -a`.

This was tested on macOS 10.14.6 and Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 12):

the richest locale support i found in python is babel.

please install by:

```
pip install babel
```

then,

```
import babel
all_ids = babel.localedata.locale_identifiers()
```

there is also extensive support for common terms translation etc.
babel is being used in various other packages.

hth,
alex

Comment: I think this Babel solution below should be the accepted answer. Currently there are 789 locales listed in Babel

Answer (score 11):

You can look up available locale names on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f).

You have to pass the long version from "Language string" in the MSDN list as value to `setlocale`. The default L10N short codes like `en_EN` which are in `locale_alias` do NOT work in general.

I have already extracted some of them as dictionary:

```
LANGUAGES = {
    'bg_BG': 'Bulgarian',
    'cs_CZ': 'Czech',
    'da_DK': 'Danish',
    'de_DE': 'German',
    'el_GR': 'Greek',
    'en_US': 'English',
    'es_ES': 'Spanish',
    'et_EE': 'Estonian',
    'fi_FI': 'Finnish',
    'fr_FR': 'French',
    'hr_HR': 'Croatian',
    'hu_HU': 'Hungarian',
    'it_IT': 'Italian',
    'lt_LT': 'Lithuanian',
    'lv_LV': 'Latvian',
    'nl_NL': 'Dutch',
    'no_NO': 'Norwegian',
    'pl_PL': 'Polish',
    'pt_PT': 'Portuguese',
    'ro_RO': 'Romanian',
    'ru_RU': 'Russian',
    'sk_SK': 'Slovak',
    'sl_SI': 'Slovenian',
    'sv_SE': 'Swedish',
    'tr_TR': 'Turkish',
    'zh_CN': 'Chinese',
}
```

Comment: This will vary by machine and installation so many of these may not be valid for the user, the locale_alias command is the correct way to get the list

Comment: the values from `locale_alias` do not work on Windows!

Comment: I was curious about your response so I just tested locale_alias on three windows machines. It worked on all three. The machines had various flavors of 2.7 installed although I note they use the Enthought distribution installed so perhaps they are doing something cool there? What do you get from: import locale; locale.locale_alias  ? And Python version/distribution?

Comment: `locale_alias` does work but its values cannot be passed to `setlocale` ("locale.Error: unsupported locale setting")! For example, `'de'` gives `'de_DE.ISO8859-1'` on default Python 2.7.9

Comment: oh, that! Yes, Windows reports more locales than can be fully used. As I heard it (caution: have not researched)  lots of windows programs install "locations" for themselves to use but don't install the full standards-compliant package - just the bits they need - so windows reports lots of locations that actually aren't supported. A lot from your list also won't be supported (or listed) though, depending on install parameters and coding. Note the MSDN link doesn't list the key codes (& also doesn't apply to Win 7 or 8). The correct code should be shown in locale_alias though.

Comment: Again: You have to pass the long version from "Language string" in the MSDN list as value to `setlocale`. The default L10N short codes like `en_EN` which are in `locale_alias` do NOT work in general! See https://bitbucket.org/snippets/schlamar/8nxR

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I've been saying, perhaps there was a miscommunication here  :)  You should edit some of this added information into your answer so I can take off the -1

Comment: I think the Babel solution below is by far more complete. Currently there are 789 locales listed in Babel

Answer (score 2):

This snippet works for me running on repl.it(python 3.8.2), Windows(3.9.1), and LSW(3.9.2):

```py
import locale
available_locales = []
for l in locale.locale_alias.items():
  try:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, l[1])
    available_locales.append(l)
  except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet tries out all the locales known to the locales package and keeps the ones that don't crash, i.e. are available. (Tested on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.3)

```
import locale
available_locales = []
for l in locale.locale_alias:
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, l)
        available_locales.append(l)
    except:
        pass
```