# python: locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Tags: python, ubuntu, utf-8, locale

my code has:

```
def sep(num, lang='en', none_is_zero=False):
    if num is None:
        if none_is_zero is False:
            return None
        else:
            return 0
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, lang)
    except locale.Error:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en')
    return locale.format("%d", num, grouping=True)
```

since i was getting that error i tried to run this to test:

```
def test(bot, job):
    print(sep(12343, 'it'))
    print(sep(11425, 'en'))
    print(sep(1234235, None))
    print(sep(42345, ''))
    print(sep(2353636, 'gergreh'))
    print(sep(None, None))
```

and i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/**/utils.py", line 192, in sep
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, lang)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 594, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/ext/jobqueue.py", line 286, in tick
    job.run(self.bot)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/ext/jobqueue.py", line 411, in run
    self.callback(bot, self)
  File "/home/**/utils.py", line 199, in test
    print(sep(12343, 'it'))
  File "/home/**/utils.py", line 194, in sep
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 594, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

but i don't get any error on windows and the function works as expected. The problem is only on my ubuntu vps.
finding some answers on stackoverflow i saw someone suggesting to use 'en_US.UTF-8' and i tried and it works even on linux. But 'en.UTF-8' still doesn't work. i could append `UTF-8` if it's needed but the api i use sometimes returns as lang_code only 'en', 'it', 'es'.

how can i get rid of this problem? on windows i don't have problems and it seems like the problem is just my linux vps with `it`, `en` etc

Comment: There's some relevant info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39506697/4014959); also see the other answers (and their comments) on that page.

Comment: thank you. as far as i read there i should solve doing 
`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale.locale_alias[lang])`
am i right? @PM2Ring

Comment: I linked to the answer that suggests using the 3rd-party `babel` module. Other info on that page suggests that `locale.locale_alias` doesn't work correctly on Windows.

Comment: i solved using babel functions to group digits. http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)

Answer (score 1):

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Adding a brief description along with the answer is appreciated.